# Position sticky not working (Element.io and VueJS)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sticky, element-ui

I'm having a problem with the sticky position on my left menu. The sticky position doesn't work.

I use VueJS and Element.io (https://element.eleme.io/#/fr-FR/component/layout).

Thank you for your future help !

```
<el-row :gutter="24" type="flex" justify="start">
      <el-col :span="6" class="sidebar">
        <el-menu default-active="1" @open="handleOpen" @close="handleClose">
          <el-menu-item index="1">
            <i class="el-icon-document"></i>
            <span>Mes documents</span>
          </el-menu-item>
          <el-menu-item index="2">
            <i class="el-icon-star-on"></i>
            <span>Mes favoris</span>
          </el-menu-item>
        </el-menu>
      </el-col>
      <el-col :span="18">
        <div class="tableDocuments grid-content">
          <!-- A table -->
        </div>
      </el-col>
    </el-row>
```

My css

```
<style scoped>

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
}

</style>
```